# Animate popup menu at specific location in Android

Tags: android, animation, menu

I'm interested in implementing some kind of a menu bar below a view (a recyclerview item to be specific) after a long press, with inflation animation.
Something like in the app drawer:
[image]

I know there are many approaches for implementing this, but what is the best solution for it today?
Using MotionLayout? Inflate a view or dialog?...